# Crating table in BigQuery from csv file located in Google Storage

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to create a Google Cloud function that automatically creates a table from simple .csv file located in bucket on Google Storage. I created new function and I wrote Python script according to the schema below. It seems to be correct, but when I'm trying to implement the function, I see the error.[here is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZBXO.png). I really don't know what is wrong with my code. Please help.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = 'myprojectname.newdatasetname.newtablename'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField('A', 'INTEGER'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('B', 'INTEGER'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('C', 'INTEGER')
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=0,
)
uri = 'gs://my-bucket-name/*.csv'

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
) 
load_job.result()  
destination_table = client.get_table(table_id) 
print('Loaded {} rows.'.format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

Comment: In your code, you are not creating any function. Check the documentation quickstart about event-driven cloud functions https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#event-driven_functions

Comment: I used this as and example https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv that's why I was thinking that it's correct

Comment: That's just a code snippet. Try combining both to create your function :)